# rebar requirements in foundation

Tags: concrete, foundation, rebar, trench

follow-up question:
I am attaching a diagram with my foundation plan. I am in north NJ where frost line 3 ft. Can you kindly look at the plan and opine; I tried to use best practice from all replies.[image]

thanks for the responses so far.
I will be digging 3 ft deep and 12inch wide trench and pouring 3500 PSI concrete in it. There is no footing but only 3ft wall below grade. My town mentioned that footing is not necessary if I make a 3ft wall below grade and fill with concrete. They also mentioned rebar is not necessary.

1. Do you think going without rebar is a good idea? since, town mentioned it, I wanted to reconfirm with all.
2. If I use a rebar, someone mentioned vertical rebar provides less strength to concrete compared to horizontal. So, if I go with horizontal, will one rebar in the center (width) and 3 inch above the bottom of the trench be fine? or do I need one on bottom (3 inch from bottom) and one on the top as well or one in the center (18 inch from bottom) will be fine?
3. Many places I have seen vertical rebars, not sure why?

thanks again.

Comment: Think on your other question you mention it being 2 1/2 story house.  Kind of concern that you do not require footing for the foundation.  Rebar is usually done as a cage, so the vertical pieces are used to tie the horizontal pieces together, to hold the concrete from cracking too bad(falling apart).  Your location in the world and type of ground would help also(add to your question, not comment).

Comment: The hook on the anchor bolts goes **under** the top steel, but do that your own way too...

Comment: It's always a good idea to include a link to the question you're following up on. May as well make it easy for people who are volunteering their time to try to help you instead of expecting them to go digging on their own to find the background to which you're referring.

Answer (score 2):

You've already stated that your town/city *requires* nothing for reinforcement. So you have no requirements, unless you investigate the path of having something designed (likely for a few hundred $) that saves you perhaps a few thousand $ in concrete cost. Unreinforced concrete needs to be much larger than reinforced concrete to carry similar loads.

For a short, wide, long foundation wall, vertical steel does very little because concrete is already quite strong in compression. The primary benefit of steel in combination with concrete is that it's very strong in tension, which concrete is not. In more extremely loaded cases steel is sometimes *also* used as a compressive reinforcement, but that's irrelevant to *this* application. Tossing in vertical bars every 4 feet as you suggested in a comment on the prior question is virtually useless, unless something is pushing very hard sideways on the middle of the wall's height, at 4 foot intervals. Since you are putting this in a ditch, I don't see that as a likely condition.

Since you are intending to use ICFs, and ICFs have built-in holders for horizontal (or angled between two different elevation) bars, you don't need vertical steel to hold up the horizontal steel.

Typical weak points (due to stress concentrations) for concrete foundations are corners, thus the recommendation to bend steel around the corners. The primary loading is the house pushing down from above, so steel in the lower half is useful for resisting the tensile loading there. Steel in the upper half can help to more firmly anchor your anchor bolts, if they do not reach all the way to the lower steel, and will also resist any tension resulting from subsidence or erosion of the soil under the footing - which are less-likely loading conditions if the soil is good, so that is less likely to have a sizable benefit. Given ICFs, and corners, I'd still at least throw a bent 10 footer in the upper brackets at each corner, because corner cracking is a thing.

If you are only going to put in one bar, 3" above the bottom (required distance for corrosion protection) is the most beneficial placement for tensile loading. Placing it at 18" almost eliminates any benefit, as that's the "neutral axis" of the beam, where there is neither tensile nor compressive loading. If putting in only two, same distance from the bottom, but 3" from each sidewall in parallel (so, 6" apart, 3" off the sidewalls, for a 12" thick wall.) If going for three, a top bar where your anchor bolts could be hooked and tied would be my choice.

It's all optional, but given (likely) thousands of dollars in concrete cost, a small fraction of the cost in steel to make the resulting concrete object more durable is math I'm in favor of - but of course when it works, you never see it working - it's when you see non-reinforced concrete crack that you might wish you had done it when, and that might or might not happen. Your city says you can skip it entirely, and you can follow that advice if you like. It will be (very slightly) cheaper.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely helpful reply. I attached a final diagram, please do tell me if the placements look fine. I do not plan to use ICF (very difficult to find what I need) rather 1 inch insulation board on both sides of stemwall; it will give me a nice template to pour concrete instead of on the mudwall. thanks

Comment: So, you want to learn the hard way. Have fun. You'd be better off pouring a footing, building an 8" block wall on top of it with a row of bond beam blocks thrown in, and grouting it. But go your own way, learn your own expensive lessons....

Comment: Good luck with the foam board holding back the wet concrete, @marcKatz. ICFs are specifically designed for this, "plain" foam board isn't.

Answer (score 2):

We design from the top down and build from the bottom up. You seem to be designing from the bottom up… this will be a problem if there is a concentrated load some where in the house, like a refrigerator, soaking tub, etc.

The Building Code requires a 12” wide footing for a 2 story house, if it is light frame construction (without brick veneer, etc.) and the soil has a bearing value of 2000 lbs. (See Table R403.1)

However, you seem to be putting a lot of extra weight on the soil by making the stem wall 12” wide from top to bottom. You’ll be putting 50 lbs. extra per foot of depth of load on the soil, compared to a 8” stem wall. If you design from the top down, you’ll know if the soil can take the load.

The wall is 3’ high, but you’ll need to keep the soil down about 6” from the top, so your depth is really only 30”.

I see you’ve changed from ICF forms to using 1” foam boards. This will not hold the concrete in line when you pour the wall because it’s 36” deep. The wall will blow out.

Looking at your rebar design, I see you do not have enough rebar at the bottom nor do you have enough for temperature steel (this will allow the wall to crack.)

You live where there is a fair amount of snow. Why not calculate the loads that will rest on the footing so you’ll know if you’ll have future problems.